# How do you make an icon change from grey to full colour on hover?

Tags: css

I have a grey facebook icon and a full colour facebook icon. I would like to have them on my website so that when the mouse cursor is placed over the grey icon it becomes the full colour one. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/) and shift position based on CSS class for element and element:hover.

Comment: This. It doesn't require an extra elements, as you can set a background-image on anything. There won't be any flicker when hovering, as it uses sprites and the user can't right click or drag the image – ideal for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, new answer with an old link:
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover shows a solution with jQuery, which doesn't need 2 images (so it saves time and resorces if you want to do a larger gallery)

Answer (score 0):

you need to have 2 versions from the Icon, one grey and another colored, and on hover, switch:

```
icon
{
  background-image: greyIconURL
}

icon:hover
{
  background-image: coloredIconURL
}
```

another way and better is [@Kon solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486231/i-would-like-to-make-icon-change-from-grey-to-full-colour-when-mouse-hovers-over/6486246#6486246)

Comment: css wont change image's src. It is only (hope you will agree) a workaround. It wont be an image, it will only be a div

Comment: Yes, agree, it is not an image, if he needs to change the image src, so your solution will work, but seams he need the answer using CSS, not js.

Comment: hmm right maybe @james can explain what he needs.. the tag suggests css but it wont be good for SEO and user wont see the image context menu, spans wont read height/width without display:block and divs.. well divs dont seem to have any downside but still not better than an img tag.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done through the filter in css.
example

```css
  /* needed code */
  .employee:hover img {
      filter: none;
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
      }
   .employee img {
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%; }
    
    /* style col -- no need */
    
    .row {
      display:flex;
    }
    .col-md-3{
      padding:5px;
      width:25%;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="row ourTeam">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12  q-pa-md employee">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
        <h6>Name</h6>
        <span>CEO</span>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12  q-pa-md employee">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
        <h6>Name</h6>
        <span>CEO</span>
      </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-12  q-pa-md employee">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
        <h6>Name</h6>
        <span>CEO</span>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12  q-pa-md employee">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
        <h6>Name</h6>
        <span>CEO</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

that easy!

Answer (score -3):

`<img src="grey.png" onmouseover="this.src='blue.png'" onmouseout="this.src='greay.png'" />`

**EDIT** use this instead of you wish to be following rules but increasing complexities and KBs

HTML

```
<img id="yourImage" />
```

JS

```
document.getElementsByTagNames('body')[0].addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('yourImage').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        document.getElementById('yourImage').src = 'color.jpg'
    }, false);
    document.getElementById('yourImage').addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        document.getElementById('yourImage').src = 'grey.jpg'
    }, false);
}, false);
```

PS this uses javascript as opposed to your css tag simply because it is a good practice to use image tag wherever possible because browsers will image as an image as opposed to a div tag where they will treat it as a content block (which is not good!).

Comment: Dunno. Maybe the OP wanted a css-only solution since it was tagged "css"?

Comment: It does not follow the principles of Unobtrusive JavaScript http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: i tried to make it one liner but this can also be written with eventlisteners and following principles. updating :)

Comment: edited to follow the rules.. :) hope this (makes sense :O) helps

Comment: The problem with this is that there is literally no point – CSS can do this with much less code, in a much more semantic way. Plus, it doesn't use a sprite, so there will be a noticeable flicker on hover. All in all, this is probably the worst way to achieve this effect. If you want a div to render like an image, change the display to inline. Other than all that, good answer! :)

Comment: how about the context menu that an image gets? and drag and drop that is an image's basic property in every modern browser. and there wont be any flicker since the javascript does not change the image src on load. and most importantly HOW in the world is using a div for showing an image a 'semantic' method? a div is for content , img tag is for images..

Comment: its like using tables for structure. plus is all of this because @james did not add a javascript tag? because i dont see any problem with my new code. where is everybody's 'use things for what they are meant for' instinct? lol :P

Comment: oh sorry @Rich i thought you said flicker on 'load' but you said 'hover' :P once the images are in browser's cache i am certain there wont be any recognizable flicker. (oh maybe there will be some flicker in ie6 but.. never mind :O)

Comment: The img tag isn't really for presentational images, and in this case, the facebook logo is a shorthand for the word Facebook. For that reason, an a tag with a CSS background image would be most appropriate. This also has the advantage of already having a hover state defined, so that the use of a sprite is easy. img tags are fine for images in galleries, or images in an article, but for presentational images, CSS + hidden text is better.

Comment: hmm okie its just that those were hard earned 6 rep points i lost for writing (quiet decent) javascript :P :'(